# Is it possible to make a tri-state bidirectional buffer without any tri-state buffers?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, tri-state

I'm currently making a computer in an application called *Smart Logic Simulator*. It does not have any tri-state buffers and therefore I cannot make a bus (based off the [DM74LS245](http://ecee.colorado.edu/%7Emcclurel/dm74ls245.pdf) chip.) Is there a way to make a tri-state buffer?

EDIT:
I don't know much about logic, and it's possible that the thing I want to make isn't a tri-state buffer, but that's what I think it is.

Here are the elements in the app I'm using:

[image: Stuff in the App 1]

[image: Stuff in the App 2]

[image: Last Thing in the App]

Comment: what are the elemental building blocks of Smart Logic Simulator?

Comment: i just added some images with all the components (mind the ad)

Comment: I had built the SN74LS245 in a program called Digital Works and was able to get the desired behavior, but when I tried it in Logism it failed to connect or disconnect and to change direction. You can refer to my question on this subject here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/450917/215954

Answer (score 2):

A tristate inverter has truth table:

```
enable, in, out
0, 0, z
0, 1, z
1, 0, 1
1, 1, 0
```

You can build such a thing with CMOS transistors. The pull up network has two PMOS in series, and ther pull down network has two NMOS in series. In connects to the lower NMOS and the higher PMOS, and the complement of enable goes to the other two transistors.  That looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHLPKC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You can build other variations on this by introducing inverters in various ways.

Comment: i dont think making stuff with cmos, pmos, nmos, etc. is possible with the somewhat limited elements i have. im not even sure if what i asked for is what i need

Comment: you might be better served asking the developers of the Smart Logic Simulator app directly, e.g. on their Facebook page https://www.facebook.com/SmartLogicSimulator/

Comment: @vicatcu or indeed by using a better-suited tool for the task at hand

Comment: @Richard the Spacecat what software would you recommend?

Comment: [Logisim](http://www.cburch.com/logisim/) perhaps? It was made for this kind of thing. It's however PC only afaik, not sure if there's anything decent enough available for mobile. :|

Comment: thats alright, ive only remade 2 chips (one for registers and a special counter for the alu), so ill only loose an hour of work. i mainly just started making the computer. ill start working on it with Logism. Thanks!

Comment: This schematic isn't quite right -- when ~EN and IN are HIGH, the nMOS network is conducting, and when ~EN and IN are LOW, the pMOS is conducting. It's only high impedance when the signals don't match. Instead, you need an EN signal for the nMOS network and an inverted EN (~EN) for the pMOS network -- this makes it high impedance when EN is low.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to just use Logism. It's much more advanced than what I was using before, and itll make things better such as not having to compensate 2 2-input and gates to make a 4-input and gate. Props to Richard the Spacecat!

Answer (score 0):

Ben Eater's 8-Bit Computer in an online simulator with a TriState Buffer
https://electra.academy/simulator/?shared=7736858c77175aa639676e7b4669f0655f0bc727

Simulating this without a special element just by using simple gates is not possible - I think.

Answer (score 0):

In order to implement a high impedance node on a bus, you need a logic-controlled **switch** that can fully disconnect your peripheral from the network.

Unfortunately, you don't seem to have that here. Every symbol on the page drives the bus either to your high logic voltage level, or to low.

In a real circuit, you can implement this kind of switch with a pair of MOSFETs and another inverter like this example of a tri-state inverting buffer:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUFWie.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The input signal, \$A\$, controls the two outermost MOSFETs. When \$A\$ is high, its connected nMOS conducts; when low, the pMOS conducts. The \$EN\$ signal turns on its connected nMOS when high, and is inverted to turn on its connected pMOS when low. I've drawn the inverter as an inverter here for clarity, but it's really just two more complementary MOSFETs, to make a total of six.

Often, this is simplified as a logic symbol which has a buffer with a third input coming out of the bottom, like so:

[image: Tri-state buffer logic symbol.]

Since a symbol like this doesn't appear in your list, you can't really implement tri-state logic.