# Implementing a SN74LS245 Octal Bus Transceivers With 3-State Outputs in Logisim

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, logisim

I'm testing out different circuit simulator programs and I was able to build the integrated circuit `SN74LS245 Octal Bus Transceiver` in a program called Digital Works. Here is the datasheet [SN74LS245 pdf](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn54ls245-sp.pdf).

In Digital Works you set up the logic gates that you need, and for the pin I/O in this application it has a tag device in which you can associate that tag as an external pin to the IC. In Digital Works, I'm able to save this circuit and its template as a macro and then be able to include that into another circuit.

Within Digital Works I was able to create an 8 bit bus and connect multiple devices to it using this 74LS245 chip. I can use the `~OE` pin which is active low to allow the chip to be either active or inactive to the bus. I can then use the `DIR` pin to set the direction of the `I/O`. If `DIR` is set `HIGH` or `1` then logic will flow from pins `[A1..A8]` to pins `[B1..B8]`. If `DIR` is set to `LOW` or `0` then direction flows from `[B1..B8]` to `[A1..A8]`. This is the desired and expected behavior of this chip.

I will show some screen shots of the logic implementation and the different simulated states it can be in.

---

Here is the logic diagram within Digital Works when all of the pins or external connections are defaulted to 0 or LOW input. This is the internal design of the IC macro circuit.

[image: 74LS245 Logic]

---

Now I'll show you a series of images in it's different states: I'll only be using 4 pin I/O's for this demonstration. I will have `A's` bus inputs as `0011` and I'll have `B's` inputs as `1100` just to show how it only flows in a single direction or doesn't flow at all or disconnects when `~OE` is set to `HIGH`. First here is the truth table of the 4 states:

```
~OE  | DIR | BUS A - in | BUS B - in | BUS A - out | BUS B - out
 0   |  0  |    0011    |    1100    |    1100     |    1100
 0   |  1  |    0011    |    1100    |    0011     |    0011
 1   |  0  |    0011    |    1100    |    0011     |    1100
 1   |  1  |    0011    |    1100    |    0011     |    1100
```

---

Here are the 4 images of the respective states:

[image: State A]

---

[image: State B]

---

[image: State C]

---

[image: State D]

---

I tried to do the same thing in Logisim but I'm having issues with it's pins for I/O. It seems that Logism is expecting for it to be either an input or an output. However, there is an option to set it to 3 states, but I'm not getting the desired behavior that I am seeing within Digital Works. Can this type of circuit with bi-directional capabilities be simulated within Logisim? If so; how would one do this, what am I missing or over looking?

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is pretty old, but may be somebody is still interested.
Indeed, it is not possible to really simulate the 74245 with Logisim : in a subcircuit, a pin may only be an input OR an output, not both, as opposed to the real 74245.

But it can be simlated pretty easyly.
First of all, you design it as a subcircuit, where for each pin A1, B1, 12, B2 etc. you create 2 pins : one input, one output :

[image: fake 74245]

Then, you can build your circuit with it. In the following, its a typical usage where you interface a data bus with a register.

[image: sample use]

When FROM A TO B is set to one, you can write some value on the bus using the BUS INPUT pin, then assert the bus. Signals are going from a to B.
When done, you just push the button below the register to store the value.
Then you can stop asserting the bus, and switch FROM A TO B to zero : one can see that now, the bus is written from B to A.

Not perfect, but the easiest I can think of to "simulate" the 74245.

Answer (score 1):

I made a subcircuit as shown in the figure below.

[image: 74245 Bus transceiver]

If you create a subcircuit that connects the same inputs and outputs as the 74245 data sheet, it will not work properly.
Instead, I defined the input and output pins separately and connected the inputs and outputs in the main schematic to accurately simulate the expected behavior.

Both input and output pins should have the three-state attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Your test circuit looks as though it's driving the pins on both sides of the simulated IC. This won't work -- you need to disconnect the drivers (square with circle inside) on the side that's currently being used as an output.

Digital Works appears to be handling this situation incorrectly by allowing the output of the IC to override the output of another driver with no warning. Logisim will (correctly) warn you when this occurs -- a simplified version of your test circuit yields:

[image]

Comment: It has tri state logic within the circuit. If the OE pin is set low the chip is enabled and the direction of the flow will depend on what the DIR pin is set to high or low. If you look at the images that are from Digital Works; you will see that the lines that are black are active high and the lines that are grey are either active low or disabled...

Comment: No, I mean in the circuit outside the IC. Every indicator (circle thing - LED?) is connected to a driver, which is actively driving the signal high/low regardless of whether the IC is also trying to drive that signal or not.

Comment: In the first image the led's on the left that are lit up are coming from the b-side bus, and the pressed buttons on the left are still on but the led's are off when the DIR is low, in the 2nd image when DIR is high, it's just the opposite.

Comment: This works fine in Digital Works because of the tri state buffers within the IC, follow the logic! If Enable is low then the and gate on the right side is active and it is sending a 1 to the left side and gate. This activates the line going all the way down on the right side that is connected to the tri state buffers' enable line. When DIR is low, it will drive the flow from B to A. When DIR becomes HIGH or 1,  It turns on the left line all the way down, and turns off the right line all the way down making flow go from A to B.

Comment: The images above are showing that the simulated circuit works within the application Digital Works. The buttons that are connected to the LEDs are what is driving the values across the wires.

Comment: Oh. I think I see the problem. Digital Works appears to be at fault here.

Comment: Not really I don't think so.

Comment: This is how this circuit is supposed to work. It is a 8 bit buffer to select which direction to send the data across a bus or to disable it any incoming or outgoing output to a bus.

Comment: Right. And your test circuit is driving inputs to both sides of the buffer. This should be shown as a bus conflict; Digital Works is simply ignoring the extra drivers.

Comment: No it's not, When OE is HIGH it disables all connections to the bus. When OE is low the chip is enabled. The direction of flow is determined by the state of DIR. Here is a section from the data sheet:   "The SNx4LS245 devices allow data transmission
from the A bus to the B bus or from the B bus to the
A bus, depending on the logic level at the directioncontrol
(DIR) input. The output-enable (OE) input can
disable the device so that the buses are effectively
isolated."

Comment: By following the internal logical design of the chip and how it is supposed to be used in practical terms, it appears to me that Digital Works has it right and Logism is failing to mimic the chips behavior. This chip has an 8 bit A & B side and either side can be input or output, but only one side is active at a time or the device is completely disconnected if EN is set to HIGH. Direction will only flow according to the state of DIR.